# Как реализовать Facebook логин во Фрагменте? Android

Tags: android, android-fragment, facebook

У меня есть `Activity`, в которой находится `ViewPager`, в котором крутятся `Фрагменты`. Во фрагментах есть `кнопка логинизации` через `Facebook`. Я пытаюсь залогинится через эту кнопку и ничего не происходит. На короткое время показывается круглый фейсбучный прогресс бар, после чего он пропадает и в логе появляется сообщение

> 06-09 19:19:20.693 28611-30332/? D/ActivityTrigger: ActivityTrigger
>   activityPauseTrigger

Когда я делаю тоже самое в Активити, логинизация и получение данных пользователя проходят без проблем. Согласно [этому ответу](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34736301/facebook-login-in-fragment-in-android) я пытался получить фрагмент из ViewPager и вызвать у этого объекта метод onActivityResult, но появляется только прогресс бар и дальше ничего. Скажите, пожалуйста, как правильно выполнить логинизацию, если кнопка находится во фрагменте?

Вот код моего Сэмпл Проекта **MainActivity.java**:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ViewPager viewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        initViewPager();
    }

    private void initViewPager(){
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult ( int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
        String tag = "android:switcher:" + R.id.viewPager + ":" + viewPager.getCurrentItem();
        MyFragment fragment = (MyFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(tag);
        fragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

Код фрагмента **MyFragment.java**:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

    private Listener mListener;
    private View rootView;
    private LoginButton loginBtn;
    private ConstraintLayout loginBtnLayout;
    private CallbackManager callbackManager;
    private String first_name, last_name, email, id ,photoURL;

    public MyFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    public static MyFragment newInstance(int position) {
        MyFragment fragment = new MyFragment();
        return fragment;
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_my, container, false);
        initButtons();
        return rootView;
    }


    private void initButtons(){
        loginBtn = (LoginButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.login_button_infragment);
        loginBtnLayout = (ConstraintLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.layoutBtninFragment);

        loginBtn.setReadPermissions("public_profile", "email");
        loginBtn.setFragment(this);

        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        loginBtn.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(loginResult.getAccessToken(), new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
                        showUserInfo(object);
                    }
                });

                Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                parameters.putString("fields", "first_name, last_name, email, id");
                request.setParameters(parameters);
                request.executeAsync();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException error) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onError: " + error.toString());

            }
        });


        loginBtnLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                loginBtn.performClick();
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    }

    private void showUserInfo(JSONObject object) {
        try {
            first_name = object.getString("first_name");
            last_name = object.getString("last_name");
            email = object.getString("email");
            id = object.getString("id");
            photoURL = "https://graph.facebook.com/" + id + "/picture?width=250&height=250";


            Log.d(TAG, "РЕЗУЛЬТАТ: - " + first_name + last_name + email + id + photoURL);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это очень странно, но если удалить во фрагменте строку `loginBtn.setFragment(this);`, которую документация Facebook требует добавить, то все будет работать.